# Exception's Stack trace not complete when throwing in Func

Tags: c#, exception, stack-trace

I have an issue where when an exception is thrown inside a method accessed via a func the stack trace is getting truncated. Consider the following simple reproduction:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void Test()
{
    try
    {
        Func<string> func = () => MyFunc();
        func();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception.StackTrace:");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace.ToString());
    }
}

public static string MyFunc()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Environment.StackTrace:");
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.StackTrace);
    Console.WriteLine(new String('*', 20));
    throw new Exception("Where is my stack trace?");
}
```

I would expect the stack trace written out in the catch block to be basically the same as that written out in `MyFunc`but in fact what gets written out as the stack trace of the exception is:

```
at FuncStackTraceIssue.Program.MyFunc() in Program.cs:line 36
at FuncStackTraceIssue.Program.<>c.<Test>b__1_0() in Program.cs:line 21
at FuncStackTraceIssue.Program.Test() in Program.cs:line 22
```

As you can see it only goes back as far as the Function where I invoked the func (`Test`). The writing out of the stack trace in MyFunc is:

```
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at FuncStackTraceIssue.Program.MyFunc() in Program.cs:line 34
at FuncStackTraceIssue.Program.<>c.<Test>b__1_0() in Program.cs:line 21
at FuncStackTraceIssue.Program.Test() in Program.cs:line 22
at FuncStackTraceIssue.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 13
```

The reason this is causing me problems is that in the real code this is being called from several different places and passing in variables and other such things and when it goes wrong I log the exception including the stack trace. I want to be able to see exactly what the code path is that led to the error and preferably without having to change how I log.

So the question is why do I not get a full stack trace and is there anything I can do to make it give me a full stack trace?

Comment: Wonder if this applies to the question of why not getting full trace. From MSDN: "However, the StackTrace property might not report as many method calls as expected due to code transformations that occur during optimization."

Comment: This is by design. If you catch the exception, you're saying that you want to handle it, and how you handle it should not depend on who called you. If this isn't the case, don't catch it. For diagnostic purposes, if you want the trace of what is above the `catch` block, why don't you just use what you're already using: `Environment.StackTrace`

Comment: As a further comment, the same results from your simple repro happen even if not using `Func<>` but just calling the method directly.

Comment: Hmmm... thanks for the comment. I think my confusion was happening because sometimes I am getting full stack traces in my error logs but that might be due to where I am logging rather than where they are thrown. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to @Dark Falcon's comment above:

This is not necessarily an issue with `Func<>`, but has to do with how the `StackTrace` property works.

From [MSDN's exception class docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.aspx#Rethrow) (emphasis mine):

> "In contrast, if the exception is re-thrown by using the statement
>   [example follows]... **the full call stack is not preserved**, and the
>   example would generate the following output [example follows]... A
>   slightly more cumbersome alternative is to throw a new exception, and
>   to preserve the original exception's call stack information in an
>   inner exception. The caller can then use the new exception's
>   InnerException property to retrieve stack frame and other information
>   about the original exception."

As a possible workaround to log the full stack trace, you might consider inheriting from the `Exception` class and adding something like a stack tracer property:

```
public class StackTraceableException : Exception
{
    readonly string stackTrace;

    public StackTraceableException() : base() { }

    public StackTraceableException(string message, string stackTrace) :
        base(message)
    {
        this.stackTrace = stackTrace;
    }

    public string StackTrace { get { return stackTrace; } }
}
```

...and, to follow through with the existing `catch` block:

```
catch (StackTraceableException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception.StackTrace:");
    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
}
```